# Linked list: Initialize Head with function?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a C# programmer professionally, but trying to re-learn C. I have been writing a simple linked list in C. I have gotten it working fine when the head-node is defined in main(). But now I want to try and initialize the head-node in a function "initializeHead()".

Here is the Node definition and Main() function:

```
struct node
{
    char value;
    struct node * next;
};

int main()
    {
    struct node * head = NULL;

    initializeHead(head, 'a');
    return 0;
    }
```

Function that initializes head node:

```
    void initializeHead(struct node * head, char vertexCategory)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->value = vertexCategory;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError: Head already initialized!");
    }
}
```

...After calling initializeHead(), it doesn't seem like anything has happened because head is still NULL.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You must pass the address of `head`, (e.g. `struct node **head`) and `initializeHead(&head, 'a');`

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may
change the value of the object pointed to.*

Comment: You know `initializeHead()` is a mis-nomer? Looks more like a broken `insertNode()` which only works for empty lists, at least after fixing.

Comment: Why do you want initializeHead to be a void function? It seems more logical for it to return its result as a return value.

Comment: @Nick Lordi  "I am a C# programmer professionally' - I have no words to express my surprise.:)

Comment: Have anyone already noted that there are no methods in C?

Comment: `void f(int i) {i = 6;}` - how come when I run `int i = 5; f(i);` then i is still 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term method is not a normative term in C and C++. Use the term function instead (or member function in C++).

According to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In fact the head is already initialized in the declaration

```
struct node * head = NULL;
```

You can check for example whether a list is empty by using comparison

```
if ( head == NULL ) { /* ...*/ }
```

What you are trying to do using the function is to append a value to a list. So the function name `initializeHead` just confuses readers.

You can use instead either `push`, or `push_front`  or some other suitable name.

The function shall be declared before its usage.

Arguments are passed to functions by values in C. The term passing by reference means in C to pass a pointer to the original object. Otherwise a function will deal with a copy of the original object.

You can imagine your function definition and its call the following way (for clarity I renamed the parameter name)

```
initializeHead(head, 'a');

//...

void initializeHead( /*struct node * list, char vertexCategory */ )
{
    struct node *list = head;
    char vertexCategory = 'a';
    //...
```

That is function parameters are its local variables that are initialized by expressions used as arguments. So any changes of a parameter do not influence on the original argument. As it was mentioned above if you want to change an original object you have to pass it by reference that is indirectly through a pointer.

Also you should free all allocated memory by the list when the list is not used any more in the program to escape memory leaks.

The function should not issue a message . It is better if it returns a code of success or failure.

For example a function that pushes a value in a singly-linked list can look the following way

```
int push_front( struct node **head, char value )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to the first parameter declaration `struct node **head`. As the original head of the list has to be changed in the function then it is passed to the function by reference that is by using a pointer to it.

The function can be called like

```
push_front( &head, 'a' );
```